# How to use Automated anchor tags feature on the Embedded Sending View

Tags: docusignapi

I have a question regarding the Embedded Sending View. Through our program, the user selects documents which are sent to the Embedded Sending View where the user then selects recipients and has the option to add fields on the documents. The documents can have automated anchor tags such as \s1\, \s2\, and so on. What we need is for the tabs, such as Sign Here or Initial, to be displayed in the add fields page of Embedded Sending, which is not happening. Templates are not an option at this time as the documents are defined by our users. I tested this in the DocuSign Console and it didn’t work there at all, no tabs came up automatically on the add fields page despite anchor tags existing on the page.

[This is the document that I tested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UazFe.png)

[This is a screenshot of the Embedded Sending View. There were two signature anchors in the document and two signers/recipients were created in the Embedded Sending View.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0EF5.png)

[This is a screenshot of the Tagging View - The Sign Here tabs do not come in automatically.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDnh2.png)

[This is a screenshot of the page to actually sign the document through the email is sent. There are no Sign Here tabs displayed.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygFye.png)

Answer (score 2):

Automated anchor tags rely on the number in the tag text matching a recipient ID in the signer's definition. In order for \s1\ and \s2\ to map to your recipients, they'll need to have recipient IDs 1 and 2.

Automated anchor tags do not work if the document is uploaded through the web console - only if the envelope is created through the API with the document and recipients defined.

The 'stock' automatic anchor tags only work through DocuSign for Salesforce. Upon closer inspection, it looks like DFS includes a set of tags in its API traffic to create an envelope.

To approximate this behavior, I created a custom anchor tag that did work. To create these tags yourself:

- Navigate to Go to Admin > Document Custom Fields
- Add Field
- Name: Anchor Signature
- Type: Sign Here (or Initial Here if desired)
- Shared: Checked (makes tag available to all users on the account)
- AutoPlace Text: `\s{r}\`

In practice, the `{r}` gets replaced with the recipient ID.

This tag definition:

[image: Anchor tag]

Results in tags being placed in my example draft that I created through the API:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. We have already the exact same custom field that you mentioned above. I'd like to clarify how you got the above result. In your case, I guess that through API, you created signer 1,2 objects, assigned recipients ID each, set the signers to the envelope, and then you got the result that Sign tabs are on anchor tags. Am I right? If it is right, that means that an envelope must have recipients in order to use automated anchor tags.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The envelope definition needs to include recipients with appropriate recipient IDs for automated tagging to work. Otherwise, you'll need to include tag definitions in the Envelope Update call that adds recipients to the envelope.

Comment: what does it means  "only if the envelope is created through the API", if i use the BTN send with docusign from the manage package, will this document be created via browser or API?